# How come identity encodes absurdity

Tags: programming-languages, logic, proof-assistants

From P5 in this paper: https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01094195/file/CIC.pdf

> Using this purely functional part, it is possible to encode many int
>   eresting notions. For instance
>   ∀
>   C
>   :
>   Prop
>   , C
>   is a logical proposition (a term of type
>   Prop
>   ) which encodes absurdity (
>   ⊥
>   ) : there is
>   no closed term of type
>   ∀
>   C
>   :
>   Prop
>   , C
>   (so no proof of
>   ⊥
>   without hypothesis) and also from a proof
>   t
>   of
>   ∀
>   C
>   :
>   Prop
>   , C
>   one can build a proof
>   t C
>   of an arbitrary proposition
>   C
>   so the natural deduction
>   rule for eliminating
>   ⊥
>   is derivable in the logic.

where

$$
\forall C: Prop, C
$$

looks entirely identity function to me, which can definitely be inhabited by a closed term. Why the author said it encodes absurdity?

If I were to encode absurdity, I would do

$$
\exists P: Prop, P \to \forall Q:Prop, Q
$$

That is, there exists a proposition which derives everything. From category theoretic perspective, it's precisely how the initial object is defined, which can encode absurdity with no doubt.

Did I misread it in a terrible wrong way that the author was actually right? How about my encoding, does it make sense to you?

Comment: Also note that your encoding of absurdity... actually encodes truth! Indeed, we can take $P$ to be $\forall Q:Prop.\ Q$ and prove the resulting trivial implication. Indeed, there does exist a proposition that derives everything: the false proposition!

Comment: @chi perfect. good to know i have reasons to learn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> looks entirely identity function to me, which can definitely be inhabited by a closed term

A proof of $\forall C : Prop, C$ is a function from an arbitrary proposition to its proof. Since a proposition isn't a proof, an identity function is not a function from propositions to proofs.

The identity function (or rather, a function returning the identity function on proofs of $C$) corresponds instead to the proof of $\forall C : Prop, C \to C$. That's even the example on the beginning of page 3!

Comment: you are right. i should sleep good before reading things.